# About pressure formula

Tags: pressure, material-science

Pressure is defined as the force per unit area applied to an object in a direction perpendicular to the surface. 
Why doesn't pressure depend on the properties of the material exposed to the force ? So pressure depends on the area of the material but why not also on the properties of that material?  Assuming we had the same area but for different materials , then the strength of pressure will be definitely different for both. So the formula of pressure should contain a parameter concerning other properties of a material , for example its density ?

Comment: The way that objects _respond_ to external pressure is dependent on material properties. The pressure you apply does not.

Comment: Thank you! I think your comment is better be written as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that objects *respond* to external pressure is dependent on material properties. The pressure you apply does not.